# How to do a SQL query with SRFs and display only distinct values?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I'm trying to think about a way to do a query with a single row function and display only distinct values.
Lets suppose that I have a table employees with the columns employee, store and salary and I want to use the SRF MAX(salary) to find out the best paid employee in each store. If there are more than 1 employee earning the MAX(salary) in one store, how can I avoid displaying more than 1 top earner per store? See the code below. The simpler the better. Thank you!

```
SELECT employee, emp1.store, emp1.salary
FROM employees emp1
INNER JOIN (SELECT store, salary, MAX(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY store) emp2
ON emp1.store = emp2.store
AND emp1.salary = emp2.salary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a cleaner way to do this:

```
    select * from 
    (
       SELECT employee, emp1.store, emp1.salary,
       ROW_NUMBER( ) 
       OVER ( partition by emp1.store order by emp1.salary desc ) rn
       FROM employees emp1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT store,  salary, MAX(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY store, salary) emp2
    ON emp1.store = emp2.store
    AND emp1.salary = emp2.salary
)
where rn = 1
```

Row_number() analytic function will assign a value of 1,2,3,... grouped by store.  then you always just pick row 1 for each grouping.

Comment: Assumed this was an oracle database?  FYI, there is no pl/sql required.

Comment: perfect, thank you. I noticed there was a mistake in the subquery I posted as well,